# parrot os wifi adapter not detected

Tags: wifi, parrotsec

I'm running Linux in a VM on a Mackbook M2, and UTM to use Parrot OS. My wifi adapter is connected to a USB connecter, and when I use the command `lspci`, the following letters appear:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU PCIe Host bridge
00:01.0 Ethernet controller: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio network device
00:02.0 Display controller: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio GPU (rev 01)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:04.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
00:05.0 USB controller: Red Hat, Inc. QEMU XHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
00:06.0 SCSI storage controller: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio block device
00:07.0 Communication controller: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio console
00:08.0 Unclassified device [00ff]: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio RNG
00:09.0 Unclassified device [00ff]: Red Hat, Inc. Virtio memory balloon
```

And when I do `ifconfig`, only enp0s1 and lo appear, not wlan0. What I can't understand is that if I run Kali linux and do the same thing, wlan0 successfully appears.
What should I do?

Comment: What should you do: This sounds like you should run neither Kali nor Parrotsec, but a fully-fledged user distro, like Debian, Ubuntu or Fedora, where networking things aren't disabled/restricted by default as much :)

Comment: By the way, I saw that from your device list, but I will add "I'm running a VM" to your question, if you don't mind.

Comment: so, couple of things: 1. Things connected via USB do not appear in `lspci`. 2. It's up to your VM control software to decide whether and how USB devices are forwarded to the VM, so you need to look there first.